# Beautify inefficient code

Tags: javascript

Hi there and thank you so much for your help in advance!

I am very new to coding and I have spent quite a lot of time to come up with this code. Fortunately it works :-) Its function is to set nav elements of a multistep section to active....I know that this is very inefficient coded, but I don't have the skills yet, to make it more efficient. Could you help me out? Thank you soooo much, thanks!

```
$('#Step1').click(function(){
        $('#Step1').addClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step2').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step3').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step4').removeClass('Step-item-active');

    });
    $('#Step2').click(function(){
        $('#Step2').addClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step3').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step4').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step1').removeClass('Step-item-active');

    });
    $('#Step3').click(function(){
        $('#Step3').addClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step4').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step1').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step2').removeClass('Step-item-active');

    });
    $('#Step4').click(function(){
        $('#Step4').addClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step1').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step2').removeClass('Step-item-active');
        $('#Step3').removeClass('Step-item-active');

    });
```

Comment: Use a class instead of ids. Then bind one single handler function to all elements with that class, and inside first remove the class from all items with that class, before you specifically add it again for the current element (`$(this)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give them all the same class. For example `class="step"`. (Forget about the IDs)

Then you can add a click function that works for all of them

```
$(".step").click(function(){
   // remove the class from all of them
   $(".step").removeClass("Step-item-active")
   // add the class to the clicked element
   $(this).addClass("Step-item-active")
});
```

Comment: Awesome. that works perfectly! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Class instead of ids, and four lines of code.

```js
$('.Step').click(function() {
  $('.Step-item-active').removeClass('Step-item-active');
  $(this).addClass('Step-item-active');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.Step-item-active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Step"></div>
<div class="Step"></div>
<div class="Step"></div>
<div class="Step"></div>
```